# SAS7BDAT file read error in Python Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, encoding, utf-8, sas

I am reading `sas7bdat` file as below into a data frame. it worked for all `sas7bdat` files, but failed for a new `sas7bdat` file today.

```
from sas7bdat import SAS7BDAT
with SAS7BDAT('test.sas7bdat') as m:
   df= m.to_data_frame()




File "C:\Users\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    with SAS7BDAT('test.sas7bdat') as m:
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\sas7bdat.py", line 366, in __init__
    self.header.parse_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\sas7bdat.py", line 1443, in parse_metadata
    done = self.process_page_meta()
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\sas7bdat.py", line 1470, in process_page_meta
    self.process_page_metadata()
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\sas7bdat.py", line 1499, in process_page_metadata
    cls(parent).process_subheader(
  File "C:\Users\venv\lib\site-packages\sas7bdat.py", line 971, in process_subheader
    name_str = self.parent.column_names_strings[idx]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried using read_sas method as below:

```
pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat', format='sas7bdat', encoding='iso-8859-1')
pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat', format='sas7bdat', encoding='utf-8')
pd.read_sas('test.sas7bdat', format='sas7bdat', encoding='latin1')
```

Can someone please suggest what can be wrong with this sas file and how to read this file.

Note- I was able to open this `sas7bdat` file successfully in SAS Viewer ( I originally through file might have some issues so verified by opening in SAS Viewer.

Also, It works using below package, but I prefer to use `pd.read_sas` if possible.

```
pyreadstat.read_sas7bdat(file)
```

Comment: Is there something different about the problem file? Does it have more variables? More observations?  Was it created with a different version of SAS?

Comment: it is coming from a different vendor and contains different set of data so column numbers etc. are different from earlier files. I am not sure if anything else is different.

Comment: The error message looks like it is trying to index past the list of variable names.  How many variables does it have when you look at it in SAS Viewer?  Can you look at it with SAS itself?  Can you run PROC CONTENTS on it?

Comment: The SAS7BDAT is very complex. One byte off somewhere and you can't read it. That byte could be in the header, metadata pages, or data pages. Also, the sas7bdat may be compressed (SAS compression). If it is SAS compressed, the python reader you are using may not support it. If you have an alternate way to read it, use that and report the bug. Hopefully, the file can be shared.  Debugging it by those error messages is probably not useful.